# Почему возникает ошибка "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in ru.todolist.config.AppConfig"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("ru.todolist.controller")
    public class AppConfig {

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            System.out.println("Create datasource begin");
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/todo;create=true"); 
            dataSource.setUsername("user");
            dataSource.setPassword("password");
            System.out.println(dataSource);
            System.out.println("Create datasource end");
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            String systemDir = "./todo";
            properties.put("derby.system.home", systemDir);
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
           bean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            bean.setJpaProperties(properties);
            bean.setPackagesToScan("ru.todolist");
            System.out.println("Create entity end");
            return bean;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean
        public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, DataSource dataSource) {
            System.out.println("Create transaction begin");
            JpaTransactionManager bean = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            System.out.println(bean);
            System.out.println("Create transaction end");
            return bean;
        }

Решил так, добавил в pom.xml:
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.roskenet</groupId>
            <artifactId>springboot-javafx-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot-javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
...
```

Comment: не может создать бин

Comment: Я понимаю, что не может. Почему? 
Проект собирается и запускается в eclipse, бины создаются, транзакции проходят, но когда собираешь его maven в jar и запускаешь, появляется эта ошибка. Заметил, если сложить все необходимые библиотеки в одну папку и указать java.exe путь к папке с классами проекта, все тоже нормально работает.

Comment: PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in ru.todolist.config.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL

Comment: добавьте лог в вопрос

Comment: @Leshey в вашем комментарии ответ и содержится, программа должна иметь доступ к зависимостям.

Comment: Победил добавлением spring boot, теперь все работает как надо.